# Way to show internet shortcut files with thumbnail of target site

Tags: internet, icons, shortcuts, thumbnails, shell-extensions

Is there a shell extension for Windows 7 (or some other way) that could let internet shortcuts show a preview of a the website instead the default static icon?

[image: internet shortcut]

Comment: You're asking too much...

Comment: What's your version of windows?

Comment: @Daisetsu: Windows 7

Comment: You can do this manually, I see no reason why it couldn't be done automagically.

Comment: @Phoshi: how do you do it manually?

Comment: @jay: Simple, take a screenshot of the site, run it through a converter to get a little .ico, and set the new icon.